# Yii2 ajax bad request (#400)

Tags: php, ajax, request, yii2

When I use this code, I get this error as a response:

> Bad Request (#400): Not possible to verify your data

```
/**
 * Active toggle
 */
$(document).on('click', '[data-toggle-active-menu-items]', function(e){

    e.preventDefault();

    var id = $(this).data('toggle-active-menu-items');

    $.ajax({
        url: 'active',
        type: 'POST',
        data: {'id': id, _csrf: yii.getCsrfToken()}, 
        contentType: "application/json; charset=utf-8",
        dataType: "json",
        success: function(data) {
            if (data.active == 1)
            {
                $('#list-' + id + ' [data-toggle-active-menu-items]').html('<span class="glyphicon glyphicon-eye-open"></span>');
            } else {
                $('#list-' + id + ' [data-toggle-active-menu-items]').html('<span class="glyphicon glyphicon-eye-close"></span>');
            }
        }
    });
});
```

I tried adding

> _csrf: yii.getCsrfToken()

and

> contentType: "application/json; charset=utf-8",
>           dataType: "json",

but that's not working

it does work when I add this to my controller, but that's no good, I don't want to disable csrf validation

> public $enableCsrfValidation = false;

How can I fix this?

Comment: shouldn't the csrf token/name be sent along with other post data, in your case, with the id, so it simply becomes: `data: {id: id, csrf_token_name: csrf_token_value}` ?

Comment: I also tried that, but that's not working

Comment: as long as you send the proper csrf name and value in your post request, there's no reason why it would not work, you are doing something wrong.

Comment: when I do it your way, I do get another error message: Not Found (#404): The requested page does not exist.

Comment: if you get a 404 it simply means your route is wrong pointing to the trees in the woods instead of your controller action. Use developer tools (F12) and see what's actually happening there in your xhr request.

Comment: check you have the updated your composer.
following is only way
 _csrf:yii.getCsrfToken()
With with your data with csrf enable.

Comment: everything is updated, but this is not working, is it working for you?

Comment: I think you do not need to add _csrf because in the cookie, the value '_csrf' is already registered no ?

Comment: this may seem silly, but have you tried sending it first then the id?
data: {_csrf: yii.getCsrfToken(), 'id': id},

Comment: have you added <?= Html::csrfMetaTags() ?>
and using $thi->beginBody() and then using register js to rejister your js code?
Also check how to send multiple data when you use $.ajax method

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This is my code now, just ignore the csrf token:

```
$(document).on('click', '[data-toggle-active-menu-items]', function(e){

        e.preventDefault();

        var id = $(this).data('toggle-active-menu-items');

        $.ajax({
            url: 'active',
            type: 'POST',
            data: {'id': id},
            dataType: "json",
            success: function(data) {
                if (data.active == 1)
                {
                    $('#list-' + id + ' [data-toggle-active-menu-items]').html('<span class="glyphicon glyphicon-eye-open"></span>');
                } else {
                    $('#list-' + id + ' [data-toggle-active-menu-items]').html('<span class="glyphicon glyphicon-eye-close"></span>');
                }
            }
        });
    });
```

Comment: what about type: 'GET' ?

Answer (score 18):

You can try this way. It's work!

```
var csrfToken = $('meta[name="csrf-token"]').attr("content");
$.ajax({
         url: 'request',
         type: 'post',
         dataType: 'json',
         data: {param1: param1, _csrf : csrfToken},
});
```

Answer (score 16):

```
  $.ajax({
    url: '$urlSave',
    type: 'post',
    data: {payload: payload, _csrf: yii.getCsrfToken()},        
    dataType: 'json',
  }).success(function(response) {
  });
```

other examples: [http://docs.mirocow.com/doku.php?id=yii2:docs#добавление_csrftoken_в_ajax_запрос_yii2](http://docs.mirocow.com/doku.php?id=yii2:docs#%D0%B4%D0%BE%D0%B1%D0%B0%D0%B2%D0%BB%D0%B5%D0%BD%D0%B8%D0%B5_csrftoken_%D0%B2_ajax_%D0%B7%D0%B0%D0%BF%D1%80%D0%BE%D1%81_yii2)

Comment: Much more better then provided by @user3534949 http://stackoverflow.com/questions/25054945/yii2-ajax-bad-request-400#answer-25995000

Comment: Sorry may be my comment has "ambiguity". You got +1 for Your answer from me. My comment means that Your answer is correct! I ithink we have to delete our comments, because they are offtopic.

Answer (score 6):

Add this code at the bottom of your layout:

```
<script>
    $.ajaxSetup({
        data: <?= \yii\helpers\Json::encode([
            \yii::$app->request->csrfParam => \yii::$app->request->csrfToken,
        ]) ?>
    });
</script>
```

Answer (score 0):

In my case i've solved this problem with blocking csrf-verification for "site/save-order" route (actionSaveOrder).

```
class SiteController extends Controller {
    ...
    public function beforeAction($action) {
        $this->enableCsrfValidation = ($action->id !== "save-order"); // <-- here
        return parent::beforeAction($action);
    }
}
```

Comment: I don't think it's a good solution to block csrf-verification

Comment: of course, but when i try to send csrf verification key to server it doesn't recognize it, unfortunately (

Answer (score 0):

i had the same issue
but i noticed that i forgot to add `Html::csrfMetaTags()` in the head section and that actually fixed it for me
best of luck

Answer (score 0):

Maybe your AJAX header `"Content-Type"` need to change on `"application/x-www-form-urlencoded; charset=UTF-8"`

Answer (score 0):

just add csrfToken to data params

```
const csrfToken = $('meta[name="csrf-token"]').attr("content");

$.ajax({
    url: url,
    method: 'POST',
    data: {param1: param1, _csrf : csrfToken},
});
```

Comment: While this code may solve the question, [including an explanation](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/114762) of how and why this solves the problem would really help to improve the quality of your post, and probably result in more up-votes. Remember that you are answering the question for readers in the future, not just the person asking now. Please [edit] your answer to add explanations and give an indication of what limitations and assumptions apply